# Finding custom objects with the same String member in an ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I have an *ArrayList* of custom objects *Bus* which contain String members *origin* and *destination*. There are get and set methods for the members.

I'd like to write a method which identifies buses in the ArrayList which have the same origin and destination.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? Can the Collections API be leveraged?

Unfortunately I cannot use any third-party libraries such as Commons or Guava.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:** I do not have control over the Bus Class so I cannot add any methods or members to it.

**Edit:** Neither am I able to define any new classes.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider to add such structure:

```
class Line {
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    ..getters.. 
    ..setters..
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And store your buses in a

```
Map<Line, List<Bus>>.
```

Don't forget to implement hashCode/equals property.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over the Bus Class. Apologies for omitting this from the Q.

Comment: You can use this Map without changing your Bus class. lineMap.put(new(Line(bus.getOrigin(), bus.getDestination()), bus));

Comment: I really like this approach but I am not able to create any new Classes. So I am unable to define _Line_.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares first with origin and then secondly with destination. Use the comparator to sort the List using `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`. Buses with the same origin and destination as another bus will now appear next to each other in the list.